# AWS CDK Pass raw text to UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to pass data to a 3rd party appliance/ami using AWS CDK V2 for Python

The appliance expects a piece of configuration data to be passed in via user data.

In the AWS Console, you are able to input userdata as text.

If using raw CloudFormation directly, I could do the following

```
UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Ref 'APIKEY'
```

I am unsure of how to do this with the CDK. When I do the following with the CDK

```
  instance.add_user_data(api_token)
```

I get

```
UserData:
    Fn::Base64: |-
      #!/bin/bash
      api-token-material
```

Is there anyway to replicate passing the material as text?

Comment: How is `api_token` defined?

Comment: Since I'm using the CDK, it is simply a python variable (str). To make it clear the variable name is "api_token" and the variable content is "api-token-material"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't well-documented, in my opinion, but the answer is fairly trivial. Use the custom UserData static method.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.UserData.html#static-customcontent

```
 per_instance_user_data = ec2.UserData.custom(api_token)
 ec2.Instance(...,
           
            user_data=per_instance_user_data,
      
        )
```

The CF Template generated looks like

```
      UserData:
       Fn::Base64: api-token-material
```